# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, enumerable

I am facing error Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

I tried to ingore null values, even though am getting same DBNull error. How to handle this error?

```
List<string> List = new List<string>();
 List = (from r in Dt.AsEnumerable()
                                 orderby Convert.ToDateTime(r["StartDate"]) descending
                                                select r["name"] + string.Empty).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're dealing with LINQ-to-Objects, you can use your own custom conversion, perhaps something like:

```
static DateTime? CustomParseDateTime(object value) {
    if(value == null || value is DBNull) return null;
    return Convert.ToDateTime(value);
}
```

and

```
orderby CustomParseDateTime(r["StartDate"])
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you think error occurs because startDate issue?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain define "issues"? if some of them don't have defined values, then... sure?

Comment: Name is having null value, this code not removing null values * where r["name"].ToString() != "" && r["name"] != DBNull.Value

Answer (score -1):

No problem. The following code will fix your problem, requires no additional methods, and unlike Mark Gravell's solution, handles r["name"].

```
var list = new List<string>();
list = (from r in Dt.AsEnumerable()
    orderby Convert.ToDateTime(r["StartDate"] == DBNull.Value ? "1/1/1" : r["StartDate"].ToString()) descending
    select (r["name"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : r["name"].ToString())).ToList();
```

1/1/0001 is the default value for DateTime. So if r["StartDate"] == DBNull.Value, the expression evaluates to the same value as "new DateTime()".

Good luck!

Comment: coalesce only works on "true" `null` - OP explicitly mentions `DBNull` in the question; coalesce will not help with `DBNull` values